# How to do a numeric reverse sort in python on a list which contains numbers and letters

Tags: python, list, sorting

My list is like this:

```
10.987|first sentence
13.87|second sentence
9.098|third sentence
```

if I do something like:

```
for x in my_list:
    sorted(my_list, reverse=True)
```

I logically get:

```
9.098|third sentence
13.87|second sentence
10.987|first sentence
```

This is because it is not interpreted as a number but I can't convert the whole string to a float.  What I want is a numeric sort of the first part:

```
13.87|second sentence
10.987|first sentence
9.098|third sentence
```

I tried using itemgetter but I can't seem to find exactly what I am looking for.  In bash this can easily be solved with

```
sort -k
```

Is there an equivalente to do this in python?

Comment: the numeric part only

Comment: @jpp's solution below should do the trick then.

Comment: If you want something more general-purpose (i.e., you're not always going to have exactly the format `number|string` and sort on the number which ignoring the string), there are good libraries for "natural sorting" on PyPI. But for this problem, that's overkill, and you want the answer by jpp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
lst = ['10.987|first sentence',
       '13.87|second sentence',
       '9.098|third sentence']

res = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: -float(x.split('|')[0]))
```

**Result**

```
['13.87|second sentence',
 '10.987|first sentence',
 '9.098|third sentence']
```

**Explanation**

- `sorted` takes an argument `key` which allows you to specify a custom (`lambda`) function on which to sort.
- The `lambda` function splits by "|" and extracts the first part to get the numeric component.
- To sort numerically, we convert to `float` and finally negate to ensure descending order.
- Instead of negation, `reverse=True` argument may be used.

Comment: note that you don't have to do the negation. You can simply pass `reverse=True` like in the OP.