# How do you sort a list with string elements by the numbers inside each element

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, sorting

How would I sort this list

```
list1 = ['John, 35.60', 'Alf, 200.13', 'Greg, 62.76', 'Paul, 555', 'George, 123.6', 'Colin, 35.60', 'Phil, 23', 'Bret, 200.13']
```

Into this list

```
list2 = ['Phil, 23', 'John, 35.60', 'Colin, 35.60', 'Greg, 62.76', 'George, 123.6', 'Alf, 200.13', 'Bret, 200.13', 'Paul, 555']
```

Basically, I have a list where each element is like `[customerName, orderPrice]`.
I want to make a function where it takes can take ANY list like `list1` and output a list (`list2`) with those same elements except it is ordered by `orderPrice`

Comment: Related: [How to do a numeric reverse sort in python on a list which contains numbers and letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49455460/how-to-do-a-numeric-reverse-sort-in-python-on-a-list-which-contains-numbers-and)

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post.

Answer (score 5):

[`sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=sort#list.sort) accepts a keyword `key` where you can enter a function; the result of this function is used to sort:

```
list1 = ['John, 35.60', 'Alf, 200.13', 'Greg, 62.76', 'Paul, 555', 
         'George, 123.6', 'Colin, 35.60', 'Phil, 23', 'Bret, 200.13']

srt = sorted(list1, key=lambda x: float(x.split(',')[1]))
print(srt)
# ['Phil, 23', 'John, 35.60', 'Colin, 35.60', 'Greg, 62.76', 
#  'George, 123.6', 'Alf, 200.13', 'Bret, 200.13', 'Paul, 555']
```

the (nameless) function i used splits your string at `,`, takes the right part of the string and returns the `float` of it.